# XSD : value not in enumeration

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, xsd, xerces, codesynthesis

i try to read from a XML document via the CodeSynthesis XSD generated files (.cxx/.hxx) and have this code:

```
1-> char* xmlFile = "C:\\Work\\MPRawDataExample.xml";       
2-> auto_ptr<MPRawDataFile> f = MPRawDataFile_(xmlFile);
3-> cout << f->MPRawDataFileMeta().PatientID() << endl;
```

Now on line 2 following error occurs:

`unterminated entity reference "D"` thrown from the `xsd::cxx::tree::error_handler<C>`

The file really exists there, also checked out [this](http://xmlconf.sourceforge.net/xml/reports/report-xerces-cnv.html) but hasnt helped

Has maybe someone a solution for this or another way how to read out from a XML-file?

-> **Solved**. XSD-file wasnt referenced correctly in the xml file, but now this below:

---

**Update**:

wrong part in XML-file:

```
    <AdditionalInformation>
        <Info name="Ag" value="225.0/220.5"></Info>
        <Info name="Vel" value="24.0/22.1"></Info>
        <Info name="CC" value="0.999"></Info>
        <Info name="AUC" value="1026/1159"></Info>
        <Info name="Abbr. from mean" value="1.987"></Info>
        <Info name="Base" value="1484/1501"></Info>
        <Info name="End" value="1787/1795"></Info>
    </AdditionalInformation>
```

restrictions from xsd:

```
<xs:simpleType name="ST_Info">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="0.999"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="1.987"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="1026/1159"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="1484/1501"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="1787/1795"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="225.0/220.5 "/>
        <xs:enumeration value="24.0/22.1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

for each `<Info>` now i get the Error `value "" not in enumeration`

but the Value's that are in the XML are in the restriction-enumeration? or do i missunderstand something?

Comment: It's reporting an error is in the XML file itself - there's something like `&D` written in there without a terminating `;`. Can you show the file?

Comment: havnt thought about this. the .xsd file wasnt referenced correct. But now i'm getting the next error, see edited post

Comment: I'd guess bad XML file again. I don't know XSD, but I'd guess the element's *contents* is restricted by the enumeration, not the value of its attribute `value`. IOW, it should probably be `<Info>225.0/220.5</Info>`.

Comment: You might also want to re-tag and re-formulate your question. It seems you have problems with writing XML to match a set criteria, not with C++ code to parse XML.

Comment: thx for advice, have re-formulated it. I dont get it why he complains even if there are exactly the same values, doesnt make sense

Comment: As I said, I believe it's restricting the *contents* if the `Info` element, not the value of its `value` attribute. Depends on the XSD and its application, I assume.

Comment: YEAH! You were right, its only a restriction for the content. Thx, stucked on this problem for so long now... Post an answer if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

Both the problems you list seem to be problems with the XML file itself, not with the parsing code. The first one looks like there's an entity reference `&D` without a matching `;` or something.

The second one probably means that the restriction applies to the *contents* of the `Item` element (the text between its opening `<Item>` and closing `</Item>` tags), not to its attribute named `value`).